# LINQ to intersect elements of complex List<T> into new List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.7 application.

Given is 1 `list` which contains parent and child elements. I need to group all elements in the list according to their parent element Id.

It's not so trivial as I have a complex typed object: `List<LinkParentChildViewModel>`

```
public class LinkParentChildViewModel
{
    public Location Parent { get; set; }
    public List<LocationLink> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LocationLink
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

Well, given is the List which can contain several Parent elements with the same Id, but different Children.

Currently I need to join/group all Child elements with the same Parent element underneath one Parent element.

I started my LINQ query, but somehow I'm stuck:

```
var joined = (from a in LinksParentChild
    join b in LinksParentChild
        on a.Parent.Id equals b.Parent.Id
    select new LinkParentChildViewModel { Parent = a.Parent, Children = new List<LocationLink>
    {
        // ...
    } }).ToList();
```

Do you know how to group all children of the list with the same parent element.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to solve your problem:

```
List<LinkParentChildViewModel> list = new List<LinkParentChildViewModel>();
//List seed
list = list.GroupBy(x => x.Parent.Id).Select(x => new LinkParentChildViewModel
{
    Parent = x.First().Parent,
    Children = x.SelectMany(x => x.Children).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

What are we doing:

1) We group every `LinkParentChildViewModel`, by the `Parent.Id`

2) We create the merged entity by the following rules

3) For every group take the first item's `Parent` and use it as `Parent` of the merged entity assuming it should be equal for everyone

4) For every group, take the `Children` of every items and merge them in a list and use it as `Children` of the merged item.

Comment: thanks Marco, exactly what I was looking for. Have a nice day!

Comment: Does this really work ? The *list* in *list.GroupBy* is empty. How can that produce anything but an empty list ?

Comment: @AndrewR "list seed" stands for "instructions to fill the list"